# javascript get value from input says Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html, api, input

I know this should be easy but I have spent hours trying to get this to work.

I am getting back JSON data from a weather api based on zip code. I want the zip code to come from and input(see below). However, when I use document.getElementById('city').value; I keep getting an error message in the console. What am I doing wrong? I know where the problem area is but i'm not sure how to fix it?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Weather API</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    li { list-style-type: none; }
    .buffer { padding: 0.5rem 0; }
</style>
<body>
    <p>My API call for weather</p>
    <div class="buffer"> 
        <input name="city" type="text" id="city" />
        <button id="submit" onclick="weatherHistory();">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id='blank'> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';
const city = document.getElementById('city').value; // PROBLEM HERE 
const input = 'zip=' + city + ',us';
const api_key = '&APPID= my-key-here';
const units = '&units=imperial';
var url = api + input + api_key + units; 


function get(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url);
        req.onload = () => req.status === 200 ? resolve(req.response) : reject(Error(req.statusText));
        req.onerror = (e) => reject(Error(`Network Error: ${e}`));
        req.send();
    });
}


function weatherHistory() {    
    get(url)
        .then((data) => {
            const x = JSON.parse(data);
            const max = x.main.temp_max;
            const min = x.main.temp_min;
            const humidity = x.main.humidity;
            var div = document.getElementById('blank');
            const api_data = "<li> Min Temp: " + min + "</li>" + "<li> Max Temp: " + max + "</li>" + "<li>Humidity: " + humidity + "</li>"  
            div.innerHTML = api_data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Oops something went wrong, please try again');
        });
}
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEUWB.png)

Comment: get and process the value when event occurs

Comment: Your `<script>` tag is in the head which means it runs before the rest of your html has loaded (thus at that time there is no input element yet). Either move the script tag to the bottom of your html, or don't fetch the input element until you need it.

Comment: Wrap your code into: `window.onload = function(){ /* Code goes here... */  };`.

Comment: CRice is right, because you are running your script before your html elements are created you are looking for something which doesn't exist yet with the problem line,
`const city = document.getElementById('city').value;`
Moving the script to before you close the html should work, ignoring other problems.

Comment: Oh my gosh....simply a script tag out of line....Well, thank you all. I knew it had to be something trivial. Works great now though.

Comment: All comments are outdated, you can do `<script src="main.js" defer></script>` just add [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) that is option 4 of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/1641941) aswer